# VS2015 internal compiler error when calling base class constexpr method

Tags: c++11, c++14, constexpr, visual-studio-2015

the following code produces an internal compiler error (VS2015)

```
struct A
{
    constexpr A(){}
    constexpr int bar()
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    constexpr B(){}
    constexpr int foo()
    {
        return A::bar();
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr B b;
    constexpr int dummy = b.foo();
    return 1;
}
```

However, if i'd remove the A:: qualifier:

```
constexpr int foo()
{
    return bar();
}
```

it will be compiled.
problem arises when these methods have the same name, and I need to invoke the base class method. (e.g. when using recursive template inheritence)

any workarounds?

Comment: How about `this->A::bar();`?

Comment: @DanielFrey same same

Comment: Have you filed a bug?

Answer (score 2):

The actual problem is `b` is declared as `const` (`constexpr` implies `const` on objects) and you are trying to call non-`const` (since C++14, `constexpr` doesn't imply `const` on methods, see [here](https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/constexpr-function-is-not-const/)) method with the `const` object...

According to the standard, you should not be able to solve the problem by simply removing `A::` nor by the `static_cast` the way you did. Pre-RTM version of Visual Studio 2015 allows you to do this only because its support for `constexpr` is preliminary and very buggy. C++11 `constexpr` (but unfortunately not C++14 extended `constexpr`) expected to be fully supported in the RTM version of VS 2015 (see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx)).

The correct version of your code is:

```cpp
struct A
{
    constexpr A(){}
    constexpr int bar() const
    {
        return 3;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    constexpr B(){}
    constexpr int foo() const
    {
        return A::bar();
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr B b;
    constexpr int dummy = b.foo();
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.
"this" should be casted to const A*:

```
struct B : A
{
    constexpr B(){}
    constexpr int foo()
    {
        return static_cast<const A*>(this)->bar();
    }
};
```

Also works when the methods have the same name.